# Write a program to create a file that consists of only 2 fields from another text file with 6? (VB2012)

Tags: vb.net

I'm using 
Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("Justices1.txt")
to create the file but I'm having trouble writing the code that will take only specific parts of the original "Justices.txt" file and put it into "Justices1.txt"
The first line of the original Justices file looks like this:
Henry,Baldwin,Andrew Jackson,PA,1830,1844
And I'm trying to get it to this in the file I'm creating (Justices1):
Henry Baldwin,PA

Sorry if this is a stupid question- I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd normally suggest using a StringBuilder but I figure your app won't be burning too many CPU cycles with something simple like this:

```
Private Sub FormatJusticesFile(filePath As String, formattedFilePath As String)
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(formattedFilePath,
                          From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                          Let terms = line.Split(","c)
                          Select "(" & IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) & "): " & terms(0) & " " & terms(1) & "," & terms(3))
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
    FormatJusticesFile("c:\Justices1.txt", "c:\Justices2.txt")
```